# `os.path.join` doesn't return str?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

in Python I wrote:

```
file_name = parse.unquote(os.path.basename(parse.urlparse(src).path))
directory = os.fsencode('./cache_folder')
file_path = os.path.join(directory, str.encode(file_name))
if imghdr.what(file_path).upper() not in ['J']:
```

But I'm getting the following warning:

```
Expected type 'str | PathLike[str] | _ReadableBinary', got 'bytes' instead
```

Why it got `bytes`? from what I know `os.path.join` returns `PathLike[str]`

and How might I fix this?

Comment: why do you use `encode()` for file name? it gives you `bytes` and this can make problem.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Do you know what `str.encode(file_name)` does ? why do you do that ?

Comment: @azro removing it didn't solve the issue

Comment: That wasn't the question. Plus, if both values are string it work for sure

Comment: I know what it does not, but yet not solved. I've posted full code

Comment: better show FULL error message - it will show where is real problem because problem is NOT join() but variables which you use inside join() - they have bytes but they should be string.

Comment: other problem can make `directory = os.fsencode('./cache_folder')` - it generates `bytes` and later you get `bytes`. Why do you use `os.fsencode()`?

Comment: BTW: `os.path.join` doesn't return `PathLike[str]` - if you use `os.path.join( string, string, ...)` then it gives `string` but if you use `os.path.join( bytes, bytes, ...)` then it gives `bytes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

`encode()` and `os.fsencode()` convert/encode  `string` into `bytes` and this makes your problem.

Use

```
directory = './cache_folder'
file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
```

OR you have to convert/decode `bytes` to `string`

```
directory = os.fsencode('./cache_folder')
file_path = os.path.join(directory, str.encode(file_name))

#file_path = str.decode(file_path)
file_path = file_path.decode()
```

Comment: Still Pycharm shows same message

Comment: Posted full code, maybe this helps

Comment: better show FULL error message - it will show where is real problem because problem is NOT `join()` but variables which you use inside `join()` - they have `bytes` but they should be string.